# OpenFileDialog Spy

Tags: c#, windows, shell, winapi, openfiledialog

I'm trying to capture the path of selected files and folders from the standard OpenFileDialog window created by another application.

I have seen that is possible to perform this task with windows explorer:

```
IntPtr handle = GetOpenFileDialogHwnd();

ArrayList selected = new ArrayList();
var shell = new Shell32.Shell();

foreach(SHDocVw.InternetExplorer window in shell.Windows()) 
{
    if (window.HWND == (int)handle)
    {
        Shell32.FolderItems items = ((Shell32.IShellFolderViewDual2)window.Document).SelectedItems();
        foreach(Shell32.FolderItem item in items)
        {
            selected.Add(item.Path);
        }
    }
}
```

However, the SHDocVw.ShellWindows () method does not return the opened openFileDialog hwnd. As windows explorer is very similar to OpenFileDialog, I imagine there is some way to do a cast having the hwnd of OpenFileDialog for the Shell32.IShellFolderViewDual2 interface like:

```
var view = Shell32.ShellFolderViewDual2.FromHwnd(hwnd);
```

Is there any alternative way?

The goal is simple, make a log of files used in standard OpenFileDialog windows. Workable in Windows 7, 8, 10.

I know, it seems a very very very strange thing.

**Edit:**

Inspect.exe give me hope:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An open file dialog is not a shell window so it won't show up in the ShellWindows list.

You can [send the undocumented WM_GETISHELLBROWSER (WM_USER+7) message to the dialog window](http://blog.joycode.com/jiangsheng/archives/2004/09/17/33756.joy), but the returned IShellBrowser pointer is only valid inside the same process. Using it in another process would cause access violation.

Once you got IShellBrowser you can [get other interfaces like IShellView or IFolderView2](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12029/Automate-the-Active-Windows-Explorer-or-Internet-E). For selection you want to use IFolderView2::GetSelection.

It is possible to inject a proxy DLL into the target process to control the file dialog, but you can't write the DLL in C#.