# ShellFolderView

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, shell

I'm trying to capture an instance of the Shell32.ShellFolderView class that is embedded in a another application window.

Something like:

```
var folderView = Shell32.ShellFolderView.FromHwnd (hwnd);
```

I need to perform operations like browsing and etc ...

It's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no generic interface for everything that hosts a shell view.

Explorer, Internet Explorer and some 3rd-party applications register themselves so you can interact with them using the [`IShellWindows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc836570(v=vs.85).aspx) interface. It is accessible by everything from [C++](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040720-00/?p=38393), [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8541532/3501) to [basic scripts](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130422-00/?p=4593).

Comment: Hi @Anders, tks for reply! I made this attempt but with no success for OpenFileDialogs references, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44931728/openfiledialog-spy

Comment: The common open dialog is not one of the types registered as a shell window.

Comment: Is possible to do some dark magic to manipulate this window with shell?

Comment: UI automation, anything else would be a ugly hack.

Comment: This is exactly my second choice. Tks